# How do you use CallerMemberName in LINQPad?

Tags: c#, linqpad, c#-5.0

So LINQPad says it supports everything in C# 5.0 but I can't get CallerMemberName to work.

```
void Main()
{
    GetMethodName().Dump();
}

public string GetMethodName([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
    return memberName;
}
```

Error: The type or namespace name 'CallerMemberName' could not be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

The type or namespace name 'CallerMemberNameAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried adding a `using` line for the namespace that CallerMemberName is in, but of course that doesn't work because LINQPad assumes the code you enter is inside of some secret hidden class and you can't put `using` inside of a class. So then I tried typing out the full namespace for CallerMemberName: `public string GetMethodName([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")` but this still doesn't work.

Error: The type or namespace name 'CallerMemberName' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices'

The type or namespace name 'CallerMemberNameAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices'

Answer (score 2):

First, the error message clearly says that to add a `using`, you need to press F4 and add it in the dialog that shows up.

But your second version should work and it works just fine for me. Maybe it doesn't work for you because you don't actually have the C# 5.0 compiler installed. Do you have .Net 4.5 (which includes the updated compiler) installed?

Comment: Of course I do. I've been using CallerMemberName in visual studio. I was just trying to do it in LINQPad to give someone at work a quick example of how it works, except I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, if I add `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` to my using directives in LINQPad:

```
public void Method1(object someArgument, object someOtherArgument,
             [CallerMemberName] string callerMemberName = null,
             [CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = null,
             [CallerLineNumber] int callerLineNumber = 0)
{
    string.Format("Called with {0}, {1} from method {2} in file {3} at line number {4}",
            someArgument, someOtherArgument, 
            callerMemberName, callerFilePath, callerLineNumber)
        .Dump();
}
```

Make sure you're using the current version of LINQPad. In the past, there was a separate version for .NET < 4.